# Junit Test with sessionfactory object

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, mocking, autowired

I have a method which have a line

```
SessionService sessionService = sessionServiceFactory.getService(params.get(STORENAME_KEY));
```

this line on the basis of storename reads the xml file and return the object.
I want to mock this sessionService Object .
how can i do it?